# How to compare two queries in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-server-2016

Hello I am new to PowerShell and coding itself. I have been tasked with creating a PowerShell script which does the following

1. Checks if IIS is installed or not. If IIS is not installed, it stalls the IIS on the server(pretty easy).
2. If the IIS is installed then it matches the Role Services with a list of our required role services and installs the missing ones.

I have till now written the following code:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
$IISFeatures = "Web-WebServer","Web-Common-Http","Web-Default-Doc","Web-Dir-Browsing","Web-Http-Errors","Web-Static-Content","Web-Http-Redirect","Web-Health","Web-Http-Logging","Web-Custom-Logging","Web-Log-Libraries","Web-ODBC-Logging","Web-Request-Monitor","Web-Http-Tracing","Web-Performance","Web-Stat-Compression","Web-Dyn-Compression","Web-Security","Web-Filtering","Web-Basic-Auth","Web-CertProvider","Web-Client-Auth","Web-Digest-Auth","Web-Cert-Auth","Web-IP-Security","Web-Url-Auth","Web-Windows-Auth","Web-App-Dev","Web-Net-Ext","Web-Net-Ext45","Web-AppInit","Web-Asp-Net","Web-Asp-Net45","Web-CGI","Web-ISAPI-Ext","Web-ISAPI-Filter","Web-Includes","Web-Mgmt-Tools","Web-Mgmt-Console","Web-Scripting-Tools","Web-Mgmt-Service"
$b = Get-WindowsFeature web* | Where-Object {$_.InstallState -eq 'Available'}

function InstallIIS()
{

    Install-WindowsFeature -Name $IISFeatures
}

function VerifyAndInstallRoleServices()
{

}

Write-Host "`nWelcome to  prerequisite installation PowerShell Script. `n`nWe will now conitnue with the installation of prerequisites`n" 
$machinename = hostname
Write-Host "Verifying IIS Role and Role services`n"

if ((Get-WindowsFeature Web-Server).InstallState -eq "Installed") {
    Write-Host "IIS is installed on $machinename`n"
} 
else {
    Write-Host "IIS is not installed on $machinename`n"
    $a = Read-Host -Prompt "Press 'Y' if you want this script to install IIS for you"
    if ($a -eq 'Y') {Write-Host "IIS is being installed now"}
    InstallIIS 
}
```

I want a code that will compare $b with $IISFeatures and will first list the features that are missing and then after user prompt install the required features and continue with the code if all the required feathers are already installed.

Any idea how I would go about it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.
One would be to use `Compare-Object` to list out the differences.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $b -DifferenceObject $IISFeatures -IncludeEqual
```

Another way would be to loop through $IISFeatures and see if values in $b are in there.

```
$featureNameList = $b.Name
foreach ($iisFeature in $IISFeatures) {
    if ($iisFeature -notin $featureNameList){
        Write-Output $iisFeature
    }
}
```

This will output to host all of the features in your $IISFeatures list that are not in the installed features found in $b.